# how to find the distance between 2 lat-lon pair coming from 2 different KSQL streams

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a KSQL data stream names 'stream_car_1' which gives me its current position in the form of a stream of lat-lon pair. I have another KSQL data stream 'stream_car_2' which gives me its current position in the form of a stream of lat-lon pair. I have to find the geo distance between these 2 cars every time on real time basis. Is this possible through KSQL? If yes, How?

Comment: What's the common field between the two streams? Can you edit your question to show a sample of the actual data payload ?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt yes i came to know that i need to common field between the two streams in order to enable a JOIN operation between them. Thank you for your answer. This helps. And Thank you for the community contributions that you have done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your exact data model it's hard to give a specific answer, but here's an example:

1. Create test topics directly through a new stream:

   ```sql
   ksql> CREATE STREAM CAR1 (ID INT, LAT DOUBLE, LON DOUBLE) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='car1', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', PARTITIONS=1);

   Message
   ----------------
   Stream created
   ----------------
   ksql> CREATE STREAM CAR2 (ID INT, LAT DOUBLE, LON DOUBLE) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='car2', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', PARTITIONS=1);

   Message
   ----------------
   Stream created
   ----------------
   ```
2. Add some test data

   ```sql
   ksql> INSERT INTO CAR1 (ID, LAT, LON) VALUES (1,53.917719, -1.801575);
   ksql> INSERT INTO CAR2 (ID, LAT, LON) VALUES (1,53.910515, -1.788787);
   ```
3. Query from the beginning of the topic

   ```
   ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
   Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' to 'earliest'. Use the UNSET command to revert your change.
   ```
4. Do a stream-stream join and use the `GEO_DISTANCE` function to do the calculation:

   ```sql
   ksql> SELECT GEO_DISTANCE(C1.LAT, C1.LON, C2.LAT, C2.LON, 'KM') AS DISTANCE_BETWEEN_KM 
           FROM CAR1 C1 
                LEFT JOIN CAR2 C2 
                  WITHIN 10 MINUTES 
                  ON C1.ID=C2.ID 
           EMIT CHANGES;
   +----------------------+
   |DISTANCE_BETWEEN_KM   |
   +----------------------+
   |1.1589376248164969    |
   ```